# Recipients bar in an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, sms

I would to insert a recipients bar in an iPhone application, a bar that list address book items when I type chars on it, the same that is used in the iPhone SMS native application. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved using a `UISearchDisplayController`. You can see how to do this in Apple's [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) example code.

Comment: No this isn't what I want. I want the same field that is in the SMS iPhone official application. The bar that have the "+" button on the right that open the address book. The bar that when I type chars in it lists names with phone number under it and if I select one of them the name appears in the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide a public API for that type of input field.  You can implement it yourself, or you can look for someone else's implementation, like [`JSTokenField`](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField).